# Is there a way to make Exceptions.Exceptions to Exceptions? I am using python

Tags: python

I've already tried to do:

`import Exceptions.Exceptions`

This still doesn't work, I've also tried but this has given me a SyntaxError:

`from . import Exceptions.Exceptions`

This is a package if you need to know.

Comment: Why do you need this Exceptions module? It is installed already when you get python.

Comment: there is no such thing not in the stdlib anyway

Comment: No its not a module its a file

Comment: I made the file 'Exceptions.py'

Comment: okay...  so that would be a module if you are planning on importing it

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to python

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question is, is there a way to shorten Exceptions.Exceptions to just Exceptions?

Comment: When importing? No. When using it later in your code? Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to import from a file `Exceptions.py` the class `Exceptions`. First you need to make sure that `Exceptions.py` is in your search path. The folder that you start your script in is usually in your search path.

Then you can do

```
from Exceptions import Exceptions
```

Afterwards you can use just `Exceptions` and it refers to the class.

Comment: I am sorry you hear you got discouraged. Thank you for telling me.